# show that the set $A$ has measure zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> Suppose $A\subseteq [0,2\pi]$ is measurable and that $\int_A x^n \cos x dx = 0$ for all $n = 0,1,\cdots$, where $\int_A x^n \cos xdx$ denotes the Lebesgue integral. Show that $m(A) = 0$.

I think that if I assume $m(A) > 0$, then I should be able to find some $n$ so that $\int_A x^n \cos x dx \neq 0$, but I'm not sure how to find such an $n$. Maybe finding some useful bounds involving cosine might be useful? I know some basic properties of Lebesgue integrals, like $\int_{A\cup B} f = \int_A f +\int_B f$ for a Lebesgue integrable function $f : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and for $A,B\subseteq \mathbb{R}, A\cap B = \emptyset$. I also know the Lebesgue monotone convergence theorem, though I'm not sure if it's useful for this question.

Comment: Stone-Weierstrass might be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\int_A p(x)\cos  x dyx=0$ for any polynomial $p$. Use Wierstrass Approximation theorem to show that $\int_A (\cos x )^{2}dx=0$. Since $(\cos x )^{2} >0$ almost everywhere we get $m(A)=0$.